# Easy way to copy rows between identical table schemas [Visual Studio 2010]

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

How do I transfer some rows from one table to another in the easiest possible manner? This is a one time thing. I was hoping I could use VS2010 copy and paste function in Server Explorer, but it doesn't allow me to paste in rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * into <destination table> from <source table>

Example:
select * into employee_backup from employee
```

You can add WHERE clauses and specify columns as needed.

As per http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/sql-server-how-to-copy-a-table/

Answer (score 3):

As the table schema is the same then you can use copy and paste using Sql Server Management Studio rather than VS2010

You could also use a T-SQL statement using SSMS

```
Insert Into dbo.TableB (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC ...)
Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC ...  
From dbo.TableA
```